# How to put a caption on an html-export'ed image?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I want to export two images side-by-side, and this works:

```
#+begin_export html
<img style="width:45%" src="test-images/a-3.jpg" /> <img style="width:45%" src="figs/a-3-boxes.png" />
#+end_export
```

Meanwhile, if I want to put a caption on a *single* image, this works:

```
#+CAPTION: Original vs. Boxed
[[file:test-images/a-3.jpg]]
```

But adding a caption to the "two images" version results in *no caption at all* in the exported .html file:

```
#+CAPTION: Original vs. Boxed
#+begin_export html
<img style="width:45%" src="test-images/a-3.jpg" /> <img style="width:45%" src="figs/a-3-boxes.png" />
#+end_export
```

How can I have both:

1. two images side-by-side
2. a single caption (which spans both images) that reads `Figure 1: Original vs. Boxed`

Thanks!

[edit]

I found this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60680002) which suggests to just put a caption on top of the html export, but when I tried this, there was no caption.

Comment: did you find a better solution that using tables?

Comment: @PKAP nope. You can always do raw html/latex and get finer-grained control, but this works for me most of the time. I did notice that the generated .tex file can't compile under `pdflatex`, but this question wasn't about that.

Answer (score 1):

As a first approximation, you can use a table:

```org
#+CAPTION: Original vs. Boxed
| [[./test-images/ex1.jpg]] | [[./test-images/ex2.jpg]] |
```

The caption is above, it is labeled "Table 1", but both of these can be fixed: the first by setting `org-html-table-caption-above` to `nil`, the second with an [export filter](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html#Advanced-Export-Configuration).

EDIT: here's a complete example with the added filters:

```el
* foo

#+CAPTION: Original vs. Boxed
| [[./test-images/ex1.jpg]] | [[./test-images/ex2.jpg]] |


* Code                                                     :noexport:

#+name: set
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/html-filter-image-width(text backend info)
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "<img src" "<img width=\"500px\" src" text)))

  (defun my/html-filter-fix-caption(text backend info)
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
      (replace-regexp-in-string ">Table " ">Figure " text)))

  (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-link-functions #'my/html-filter-image-width)
  (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-table-functions #'my/html-filter-fix-caption)

  (setq org-html-table-caption-above nil)
#+end_src


#+name: reset
#+begin_src elisp
  (setq org-export-filter-link-functions (delete #'my/html-filter-image-width org-export-filter-link-functions))
  (setq org-export-filter-table-functions (delete #'my/html-filter-fix-caption org-export-filter-table-functions))
  (setq org-html-table-caption-above t)
#+end_src
```

You have to watch out that the regexps don't match unintended portions of the buffer.

I like putting code in code blocks in a special `Code` section that's marked `noexport`, at the end of the file , but there are other ways of doing it (e.g. you can define the functions in your init file, but set the variables through the [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) mechanism.)
When you open the file, do `C-c C-c` on the first code block to set up everything, then `C-c C-e h h` to export. Note that the variables are global, so you might want to run the second code block before you kill the buffer to reset the values to what they were before (assuming that you have not changed the default value of `org-html-table-caption-above` which is `t`).

Comment: I need to shrink both of the images; is that possible with the table method?

Comment: Yes, with another export filter: see the edited answer.

Comment: Wow, that export filter is horrifying. Maybe I don't want captions after all... :)

Comment: What's horrifying about it?

Comment: No offense meant. This is a practical solution, but when I tried it, the changes were not applied. Might be a conflict with something in my config file. I do think it's nice to have this functionality contained in the org file, but I have an aversion to using regex on html (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2037637). For most cases it works fine - but it creates edge cases, such as the body of my document now can't contain the string `>Table `.

Comment: None taken. I agree completely about using regexes for most purposes, particularly when they need to be targeted this way. One saving grace is that the filters are only applied in certain situations., e.g. the caption filter is only applied to tables (after they are transcoded - to HTML in this case), so you only need to worry about `>Table` in the caption; but if you have a "real" table as well as a "fake" table tthat is used for images as above, then you will need to make the regex more specific in order to avoid the caption for both of them to be changed to `>Figure`. But with a little ...

Comment: ... care, it should work reasonably well. As for why it didn't work in your case, try with `emacs -q` (that's almost always the first debugging step); and check the values of the three variable to make sure that they are set correctly. That should be all that's needed: if the filter functions are not defined, you'll get errors but those should be easy to diagnose.